# How to use the AWS API Gateway Java SDK to access a Webservice

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-api-gateway

I have the following endpoint that a client sent me:

> https://**{restapi_id}**.execute-api.**{region}**.amazonaws.com/test/v1/items?type=ABC

Since this request needs to be called with the AWS Authorization process I wanted to use the API Gateway SDK, but I can't find a straightforward example on how to call it.
I was able to successfully test the API call using Postman (as exaplained in the AWS docs), but I don't know how to specify it using the SDK.
The ENDPOINT should be the full URL?
How should I make a call beyond this code? I tried using the GetResourceRequest, but that doesn't seem right. If so, what part of this URL I have is the resource?

This is code where I'm stuck with:

BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);

```
AmazonApiGatewayClient api = new AmazonApiGatewayClient(awsCreds);
api.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
api.setServiceNameIntern("execute-api");
api.setEndpoint(ENDPOINT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an open-source generic SDK you can use to do this: https://github.com/rpgreen/apigateway-generic-java-sdk

You can also generate your own SDK as per https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/api-gateway-java-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

AmazonApiGatewayClient is for managing the apis, you cannot use it to call your api.

We just launched support to generate a Java SDK for an apis, you can use that to call your api ([link to docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-call-apigateway-generated-java-sdk.html)). Note that you need to generate the SDK from the export tab in the stage.